# How do you debug a Rails application?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, netbeans

Is it possible to debug a Rails application in a similar way to a Java application - setting breakpoints and stepping into the code?

What are the best tools for this?

I have a hybrid Java/Ruby on Rails application which I can run in Eclipse or Netbeans.

I would like to step into some code in this app and try to figure out the cause of a problem I'm having.

In Eclipse if I set a breakpoint in my `blog_controller` and then choose the 'Debug' button, it seems to use the **ruby-debug-ide** gem to execute the code but I get this unhelpful output and no option to step into any source:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.5) listens on localhost:56726
    ./war/WEB-INF/app/controllers/blog_controller.rb:1
    C:/Ruby18/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.5/lib/ruby-debug.rb:101:in `debug_load'
    C:/Ruby18/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.5/lib/ruby-debug.rb:101:in `debug_program'
    C:/Ruby18/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.5/bin/rdebug-ide:82
    C:/Ruby18/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
    C:/Ruby18/bin/rdebug-ide:19
Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant ApplicationController
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is all I can expect.

Answer (score 8):

The debugger I use the most is the [ruby-debug](http://www.datanoise.com/articles/2006/7/12/tutorial-on-ruby-debug) gem, which is a gdb-esque command line debugger. Once you learn a few commands it is very quick and effective, and provides you with some handy features like being able to fire up `irb` in the context of your program and make on-the-fly changes.

And being command line based it comes in handy when you need to debug a on a remote server.

Comment: This is the method that I go with and I really like it.

Here's a link that features the debugger command in black, easy to read text as opposed to light gray :-)  http://blog.nanorails.com/articles/2006/7/14/a-better-rails-debugger-ruby-debug

Comment: This is a must-know! There are plenty of situations where an IDE may not be around! Here's a guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 6):

**You can expect more.**  I have used Aptana's [RadRails](http://www.aptana.com/rails) version of Eclipse to debug a Rails app as you describe--setting breakpoints and stepping through the code.

**You may be doing something wrong.**  It looks as if it is trying to debug an individual controller file, rather than debugging the Rails app.  When I try to execute a controller file from the command line, I get a similar message:

```
C:\workspace\myapp\app\controllers>ruby users_controller.rb
users_controller.rb:1: uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)
```

In Aptana RadRails, I choose `Run > Debug As > Ruby Application` to debug the app.

Answer (score 3):

For the vim users I strongly recomend looking into the [vim-ruby-debugger](http://github.com/astashov/vim-ruby-debugger/tree/master), which fits in great with Tim Pope's rails.vim scripts.

It gives you a handy `:Rdebugger` command, allows you to set breakpoints and open a split window to display variable values.

Answer (score 3):

maybe not relevant, but I wanted to post somewhere: got the error: "undefined method `run_init_script' for Debugger:Module" running the debugger in rails 2.3.2.  Did a sudo gem install ruby-debug and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just setting up breakpoints (I actually just **puts** to console) for 99% of debugging with RoR - this method is simple and usable across any IDE, so you never need to learn how a new debugger works.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had the same problem with Aptana. `Run > Debug As > Ruby Application` just doesn't work. I finally made the debugger work by going to the `Servers` tab, and then start the server in `debug mode`. After that, set some breakpoints and trigger the corresponding action. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging? That's just knowing where to look in the case of Ruby (and by extension, Rails) most of the time.

The problem in this case is that you probably still have your `ApplicationController` called *application.rb* where it should be renamed to *application_controller.rb*.

Answer (score 0):

Debuggin in rails is simple if you know how to read the error stacktrace!! But if you need to explicitly watch out the values during the runtime then u can use the rails  breakpointer.Below is the link to how-to on breakpointer ..hope this helps!!!

http://destiney.com/blog/rails-breakpointer

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Eclipse (never worked well for me) or Aptana (not tried) but from experience I can say that both [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html) and [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) will do what you want. I both cases you should probably make sure that the ruby-debug-base and ruby-debug-ide gems are up-to-date: RubyMine in particular didn't work for me until that was done.